# Regex preg_match change only special character between quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$value = "abrak'adabra' baba";

$pattern = array();
$replacement = array();

$pattern[] = '/(\'[^\']+\')|(a)/e';
$replacement = "strlen('\\2') ? 'i' : '\\0'";
```

The code above change **abrak'adabra' baba** into **ibrik'adabra' bibi**

What I want to do is to change **abrak'adabra' baba** into **abrak'idibri' baba**. How to do that?

Honestly I don't even really understand the regex pattern above.
There are what I know and I don't know about the code:

- In $pattern say: (any word which contain has two quotes and no quote between) or (character "a"). In the replacement, php code such a strlen will works because /e modifier will be used. But I can't understand why is it an "or" logic there.
- If length of the second part in the pattern (the a character) is more than zero, than replace it with "i", else do something else (I don't understand what \0 means)

I'll appreciate any help. This regex stuff has frustating me :(

Comment: `\\0` is the whole match. It will simply reinsert the original word the regex found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `e` modifier (eval) in patterns is dangerous, as someone could potentially execute malicious code on your server (see [the manual's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) section on that for more).

Instead, if you need to do extra processing on matched items, you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
// Find all characters between single quotes
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\'(.*?)\'/', function($matches){
    // Replace 'a' with 'i' in found matches
    return '\''.str_replace('a', 'i', $matches[1]).'\'';
}, $value);
```

If all you're doing is replacing `a` with `i` between the quotes, there may be more optimal ways to go about it, but this way you have room for more advanced processing on the strings found between quotes.

Comment: OMG, I really forget if I can use preg_replace_callback.
Thanks a lot :)